# function call history and graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, profile, graphviz

I've been trying to get a tool/code that saves the function call history and somehow plots it. I have seen several tools (fdep.m, GraphViz's dot) but can't quite find what I am looking for. Before writing something that does this, does anyone know if such tool exists?

For instance,

fun1.m contains `fun1()`, `fun2()` and a call to `fun3()`.
fun3.m contains `fun3()`

Say `fun1()` calls `fun2()` and then `fun1()` call `fun3()`. The plot would display something like

start->`fun1()`,
`fun1()`->`fun2()`,
`fun2()`->`fun1()`,
`fun1()`->`fun3()`,
`fun3()`->`fun1()`,
`fun1()`->end.

Do you get the idea?

Matlab's profile tool does something similar but it 'profiles' every single function called, and I don't care about matlab's functions, just mine.

Comment: I can't think why anyone would make a tool for this when MATLAB's profiler does such a good job... Why don't you just ignore the calls to built-in functions when they come up in profiler results, if they're not what you're interested in?

Comment: You can build a tree from the output of [FEX: fdep()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17291-fdep-a-pedestrian-function-dependencies-finder)

Comment: fdep partially does what I'm in search for. However, it does not list the function calls in a chronological order, but rather by alphabetical order.